# node.js returns null push messages

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, push-notification

I want to implement pushmessages in my phonegap application.

I am using phonegap and followed the tutorial from http://devgirl.org/2013/07/17/tutorial-implement-push-notifications-in-your-phonegap-application/.

But when I run node.js and type node notify.js it returns null.

Could someone help me out?

Code I have used:

notify.js

```
var gcm = require('node-gcm');
var message = new gcm.Message();

//API Server Key
var sender = new gcm.Sender('MY SENDER ID');

var registrationIds = [];


// Value the payload data to send...
message.addData('message',"Bericht ontvangen!");
message.addData('title','Sample APP');
message.addData('msgcnt','3'); // Shows up in the notification in the status bar
message.timeToLive = 3;// Duration in seconds to hold and retry to deliver the message in GCM before timing out. Default 4 weeks if not specified

registrationIds.push('MY REGID');
/**
 * Parameters: message-literal, registrationIds-array, No. of retries, callback-function
 */


sender.send(message, registrationIds, 4, function (result) {
    console.log(result);
});

index.js:

/*
 * Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
 * or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
 * distributed with this work for additional information
 * regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
 * to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
 * "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
 * with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
 * software distributed under the License is distributed on an
 * "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
 * KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
 * specific language governing permissions and limitations
 * under the License.
 */
var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    // Bind Event Listeners
    //
    // Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
    // 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    // deviceready Event Handler
    //
    // The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
    // function, we must explicity call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    },
    // Update DOM on a Received Event
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
        var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
        var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

        listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
        var pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
        if (device.platform == 'android' || device.platform == 'Android') {
            alert("Register called");
            pushNotification.register(this.successHandler, this.errorHandler,{"senderID":"130874160086","ecb":"app.onNotificationGCM"});
        }
        else {
            alert("Register called");
            pushNotification.register(this.successHandler,this.errorHandler,{"badge":"true","sound":"true","alert":"true","ecb":"app.onNotificationAPN"});
        }
    },
    // result contains any message sent from the plugin call
    successHandler: function(result) {
        alert('Callback Success! Result = '+result)
    },
    errorHandler:function(error) {
        alert(error);
    },
    onNotificationGCM: function(e) {
        switch( e.event )
        {
            case 'registered':
                if ( e.regid.length > 0 )
                {
                    console.log("Regid " + e.regid);
                    alert('registration id = '+e.regid);
                }
            break;

            case 'message':
              // this is the actual push notification. its format depends on the data model from the push server
              alert('message = '+e.message+' msgcnt = '+e.msgcnt);
            break;

            case 'error':
              alert('GCM error = '+e.msg);
            break;

            default:
              alert('An unknown GCM event has occurred');
              break;
        }
    },
    onNotificationAPN: function(event) {
        var pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
        alert("Running in JS - onNotificationAPN - Received a notification! " + event.alert);

        if (event.alert) {
            navigator.notification.alert(event.alert);
        }
        if (event.badge) {
            pushNotification.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(this.successHandler, this.errorHandler, event.badge);
        }
        if (event.sound) {
            var snd = new Media(event.sound);
            snd.play();
        }
    }
};
```

and when I open node.js go to my folder where notify.js is located the result I get is 'null'.

Comment: Can you add some code and log messages? What steps have you taken to debug this problem?

Comment: I have created a sample app. In my assets folder a www folder. Then created a file called index.html, created a folder js and created index.js and notify.js. I add the code in my question

Comment: Just checking: You run the app on a phone an use the proper device_token? The phone registers properly for APNS?

Comment: Its for android and I tried to run it on my own phone. But I did not try it for an APN. If I edit my gcm.Sender(); to a random other number I get the message Unauthorized. So I guess its the device_token, but I can check it 100 times i guess it is the good one...

Comment: @Drogon The gcm.Sender is the Api Key, which you obtain from Google's GCM service when registering your App for Cloud Messaging. Judging from what you say, this should be correct. The registrationId, or APIDs are a totally different thing. These are received by your device after it registers with GCM. You need this, to be able to push to the device. In your code you put it where it says 'MY REGID'. Do you have that? It may change, as well, when reinstalling the app.

Answer (score 0):

Try building with:

```
cordova platform add android
cordova build android
```

instead of with:

```
ionic platform add android
ionic build android
```

I had the same problem when I followed this tutorial: http://devgirl.org/2014/12/16/push-notifications-sample-app-with-ionic-and-ngcordova/ but building with cordova solved it for me.