# Node.js - null but authorised

Tags: android, node.js, cordova

I got this Unauthorized null message when I try trigger node script for my push notification.

[image]

I'm using this sample code for my push notification.

https://github.com/hollyschinsky/PushNotificationSample30/

Please refer this site for your reference.

http://devgirl.org/2013/07/17/tutorial-implement-push-notifications-in-your-phonegap-application/

I already check this solution but it still didn't work. Why?

[node.js returns null push messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18874030/node-js-returns-null-push-messages)

After I insert the correct API key, we got authorised but null.

Comment: Looks like you do not have an api key

Comment: already had inside google developer console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually "null" in the case means it is a success. The problem is when you run your application in local environment and the device is connected to wifi. There is a certain case that firewall block the traffic from the outgoing connection ports which are used by GCM (5228,5229,5230).

You can refer to the site as a reference
http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/http.html

Comment: Even im facing the same null response. So how to send the message to show the notification in device.

Comment: I am having same problem it returns null value so can somebody guide how to resolve it ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have not registered for an api key. This is from the url you posted.

```
 var gcm = require('node-gcm');
var message = new gcm.Message();

//API Server Key
var sender = new gcm.Sender('AIzaSyCDx8v9R0fMsAsjoAffF-P3FCFWXlvwLhg');
var registrationIds = [];

// Value the payload data to send...
message.addData('message',"\u270C Peace, Love \u2764 and PhoneGap \u2706!");
message.addData('title','Push Notification Sample' );
message.addData('msgcnt','3'); // Shows up in the notification in the status bar
message.addData('soundname','beep.wav'); //Sound to play upon notification receipt - put in the www folder in app
//message.collapseKey = 'demo';
//message.delayWhileIdle = true; //Default is false
message.timeToLive = 3000;// Duration in seconds to hold in GCM and retry before timing out. Default 4 weeks (2,419,200 seconds) if not specified.

// At least one reg id required
registrationIds.push('APA91bwu-47V0L7xB55zoVd47zOJahUgBFFuxDiUBjLAUdpuWwEcLd3FvbcNTPKTSnDZwjN384qTyfWW2KAJJW7ArZ-QVPExnxWK91Pc-uTzFdFaJ3URK470WmTl5R1zL0Vloru1B-AfHO6QFFg47O4Cnv6yBOWEFcvZlHDBY8YaDc4UeKUe7ao');

/**
 * Parameters: message-literal, registrationIds-array, No. of retries, callback-function
 */
sender.send(message, registrationIds, 4, function (result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: authorised but got null value